# Windows containers on ECS shows RUNNING but dont do anything

Tags: windows, docker, containers, amazon-ecs

I have a `microsoft/iis` task set on a ECS cluster running on AMI optimized windows 2016 server.
The task starts fine (it shows RUNNING), but after a few hours, it just stops with: `Essential container in task exited`.

Looking at the EC2 instance, I can see the container running, but it does not show the regular logs I expect on this particular container.
Another curious thing is that if I manually do a `docker run <my image>` on the EC2, it starts the container and the log is populated.

Any idea what could be wrong?

**EDIT**

adding task definition (JSON format)

`{
  "ipcMode": null,
  "executionRoleArn": null,
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "dnsSearchDomains": null,
      "environmentFiles": null,
      "logConfiguration": null,
      "entryPoint": [
        "powershell",
        "-Command"
      ],
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 8080,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "containerPort": 80
        }
      ],
      "command": [
        "New-Item -Path C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\index.html -ItemType file -Value '<html> <head> <title>Amazon ECS Sample App</title> <style>body {margin-top: 40px; background-color: #333;} </style> </head><body> <div style=color:white;text-align:center> <h1>Amazon ECS Sample App</h1> <h2>Congratulations!</h2> <p>Your application is now running on a container in Amazon ECS.</p>' -Force ; C:\\ServiceMonitor.exe w3svc"
      ],
      "linuxParameters": null,
      "cpu": 0,
      "environment": [],
      "resourceRequirements": null,
      "ulimits": null,
      "dnsServers": null,
      "mountPoints": [],
      "workingDirectory": null,
      "secrets": null,
      "dockerSecurityOptions": null,
      "memory": null,
      "memoryReservation": null,
      "volumesFrom": [],
      "stopTimeout": null,
      "image": "microsoft/iis",
      "startTimeout": null,
      "firelensConfiguration": null,
      "dependsOn": null,
      "disableNetworking": null,
      "interactive": null,
      "healthCheck": null,
      "essential": true,
      "links": null,
      "hostname": null,
      "extraHosts": null,
      "pseudoTerminal": null,
      "user": null,
      "readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
      "dockerLabels": null,
      "systemControls": null,
      "privileged": null,
      "name": "windows_sample_app"
    }
  ],
  "placementConstraints": [],
  "memory": "1024",
  "taskRoleArn": null,
  "compatibilities": [
    "EC2"
  ],
  "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:<my-region>:<my-id>:task-definition/windows-simple-iis:1",
  "family": "windows-simple-iis",
  "requiresAttributes": [],
  "pidMode": null,
  "requiresCompatibilities": [],
  "networkMode": null,
  "cpu": "512",
  "revision": 1,
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "inferenceAccelerators": null,
  "proxyConfiguration": null,
  "volumes": []
}`

Comment: What does your task definition look like?

Comment: @Ali I have updated the question

Comment: For a windows task CPU shares should not be zero. `"cpu": 0`.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html ->
On Windows container instances, the CPU limit is enforced as an absolute limit, or a quota. Windows containers only have access to the specified amount of CPU that is described in the task definition.

Updating the CPU shares should get everything running and logs to populate.

Comment: @Prashant awesome, I was able to run the `iis` container... now I am trying to solve another one. You can post your comment as an answer, I will accept it. Tks

Comment: Glad it worked out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a windows task CPU shares should not be zero. "cpu": 0.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html

> On Windows container instances, the CPU limit is enforced as an absolute limit, or a quota. Windows containers only have access to the specified amount of CPU that is described in the task definition. Updating the CPU shares should get everything running and logs to populate.